# Add or remove fields in Symfony 3 form type according to the environment

Tags: forms, symfony

On my site, people can post comments on my posts, and I can reply to them from my back office.

I want people to fill a recaptcha on the front-office, so I used EWZRecaptchaBundle, and made the following `CommentaireType` :

```
<?php

namespace Babdelaura\BlogBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use EWZ\Bundle\RecaptchaBundle\Form\Type\EWZRecaptchaType;
use EWZ\Bundle\RecaptchaBundle\Validator\Constraints\IsTrue as RecaptchaTrue;

class CommentaireType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('auteur', TextType::class)
            ->add('email', EmailType::class, array('required' => false))
            ->add('site', TextType::class, array('required' => false))
            ->add('contenu', TextareaType::class)
            ->add('recaptcha', EWZRecaptchaType::class, array(
                'mapped'      => false,
                'constraints' => array(new RecaptchaTrue())
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Babdelaura\BlogBundle\Entity\Commentaire'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'babdelaura_blogbundle_commentaire';
    }
}
```

But now, I have a recaptcha on my back-office too, and I don't want it.

Before Symfony 3 and FQCN for types I used to do `new CommentaireType(true)` in my back office, retrieve the boolean in `CommentaireType::__construct`, and add the recaptcha if is was `true`. But now I can't do this anymore.

Does somebody have a clean solution to handle that case ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `options` when you call your service to pass a boolean for example like this :

```
$form = $this->createForm(new CommentaireType(), $commentaire, array(
        'recaptcha' => false,
));
```

and then in your CommentaireType:

```
class CommentaireType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('auteur', TextType::class)
            ->add('email', EmailType::class, array('required' => false))
            ->add('site', TextType::class, array('required' => false))
            ->add('contenu', TextareaType::class);
        if($options['recaptcha']) {
           $builder
            ->add('recaptcha', EWZRecaptchaType::class, array(
                'mapped'      => false,
                'constraints' => array(new RecaptchaTrue())
            ));
        }
     }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Babdelaura\BlogBundle\Entity\Commentaire',
            'recaptcha' => false,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'babdelaura_blogbundle_commentaire';
    }
}
```